# What is the meaning of $x*\sqrt{3} \mod 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the meaning of $x*\sqrt{3} \mod 1$? 
I'm trying to understand this:

$$5( x*\sqrt{3} \mod 1) $$

If we talk about: $x=19,22,48,98$ what will be the result?

I don't know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\mod 1$ is fractional part of $n$ (for example: if $n=3.14$ then $n\mod 1=3.14\mod1=\{3.14\}=0.14$). In this case
$$5(x\sqrt3\mod1)$$
for $x=19$ it will be
$$5(19\sqrt3\mod1)\approx5(32.909\mod1)=5\cdot0.909=4.545$$
Similar, you can do it for $22,48,98$.

Answer (score 3):

If $r$ is a real number, $r$ mod $1$ is the fractional part of $r$. It can also be written $\{r\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a notation of the fractional part of the expression.

See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part